# How to create Peer Groups in Django?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

How can I create a Peer Group in Django?

I have tried the following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    peers = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)
```

Now there are for example 3 Persons (A, B, C).

A is connected to B.
B is connected to C.

A is not connected to C.

**The problem**:
 A should also be connected to C, because B and C are connected.

How can i do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a simple ManyToManyField. Have you considered simply adding a Group model with a 1:N relation to Person?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you send me a rough solution to the problem? I have read about it but I am not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Persons to a group like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey(to=Group, related_name="members", blank=True, null=True)
```

You could then right all sorts of extenstions on the Person class to access/manage peers:

```
@property
def peers(self):
    return self.group.members

def add_peer(self, person: Person):
    # This method assumes that
    # 1. The person 'self' is already in an existing group
    # 2. The person 'person' is not yet in a group.
    # Edge cases like both persons already being in a group, 
    # or person B being in a group while person A is not require some additional checks.
    self.group.members.add(person)
```

The downside of this solution is that the connection from A to C is not automagically determined, so if you wanted to connect one peer-group to another, you'd need to manually merge the two groups into one, which can get expensive very quickly.